# How to count the number of columns required by a japanese-english mixed string?

Tags: c#, string, character-encoding, string-length

My string contains a mix of japanese (double width) and english (single width) characters:

```
string str = "女性love";
```

In C#, my method has to count japanese characters as two columns and english characters as one.
So that the above string should get me a 8 columns :

```
2 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 8
```

Comment: What counts as an "English" character, exactly? What about accented characters? Do you not have an appropriate `Encoding` you can use? Presumably you'd need to actually represent the string as bytes at some point...

Comment: He is probably referring to alphabets as opposed to Asian characters, but note that some Asian character sets actually contain double-width alphabets.

Comment: Yes it's about counting double-width characters as equivalent to two single-width characters.

Comment: Aren't you really asking for the number of "columns" instead of the number of "bytes"?

Comment: @dan04 "columns" sounds like the right term. I was just not aware of it. I will edit my question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probbaly you want something like this, very rough one, but by working a little bit on it you can make it much nicer:

```
    string str = "女性love";
    int iTotal = 0;

    str.ToList().ForEach(ch=>{
        int iCode = ch;
        if(iCode>= 65 && iCode <= 122)
            iTotal++;
        else 
            iTotal +=2;
    });

//65 is 'a', 122 is 'z'.  iTotal = 8 //in this case
```

Now what about why  `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str).Length` returns 10, it simply cause `UTF8` ecoding specification. Follow this link [Joel on Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) and read entire article. In particular here is most importnat stuff in regard of this question:

> In UTF-8, every code point from 0-127 is stored in a single byte.
>   Only code points 128 and above are stored using 2, 3, in fact, up to 6
>   bytes

Check your Japanese letters code points and you will figure out an aswer on why it returns 10.

**EDIT**

Pay attention that this code, actually separate English letters from "others", and not *only from Japanese ones*. If you need to filter only on Japanese ones, cause may be you need to deal with Arabic, Ebraic, Russian or whatever, you need to know *limits*, in terms of codes, of Japanese alphabet.

Regards.

Comment: This is it ! Actually this covers my specific need :             str.ToList().ForEach(ch => { int iCode = ch; if (iCode < 128) iTotal++; else iTotal += 2; });
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, this would force the count to be what the OP is looking for but is that really what he needs?  My question would be, how is he so sure that the Japanese characters are "double width"?  His example doesn't seem to match any encoding format that I am aware of.

Comment: @Jelly: you're welcome. Read an article, by the way, really good one.

Comment: @RLH: you're right, but probbaly the point that he doesn't need any encoding, he just wants to separate English leters from others. Actually I will edit a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
int bCnt = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str).Length; //Select the appropriate encoding, if not UTF8
```

Comment: I tried all encodings and can't get 8. ASCII gives 6, BigEndianUnicode gives 12, Unicode gives 12, UTF32 gives 24, UTF7 gives 12, UTF8 gives 10.

Comment: @JellyAma, are you asking which Encoding to use, or are you simply enumerating the available options?  Only you can know which encoding your application is using.  If you are accepting "what ever is default", it is most likely Encoding.Unicode.

Comment: I was saying that simply counting the bytes based on encoding doesn't seem to work as the result has to be 8.

Comment: This is because UTF is the closest to what you are looking for and, I think, the two Japanese characters are actually contained in 3 bytes each.  Why does the count have to be 8?  Are you sure that the first two characters are two bytes each?

Comment: They very well may be occupying 3 bytes but my method has to *count* them as 2 bytes because they are double-width characters.